# What ciphers do I need to disable in tomcat to match a specific apache conf?

Tags: tls, encryption, rsa

I have instructions to disable weak ciphers in apache by adding `SSLCipherSuite ALL:!MD5:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM` to my httpd.conf.

I am actually running tomcat, and in my server.xml file I have the following ciphers enabled...

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

Can anyone tell me which ones would need to be removed to match what would normally be going into the httpd.conf?

Comment: This [similar question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19846020/4072843) might be of help/interest.

Comment: Besides removing RC4 I guess you would also need to sort AES128 and SHA1 to the end of the list (as they match +MED after +HIGH).you can actually list all OpenSSL ciphers matching the Spec with the ciphers command and then compare the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Removing these ones should do the trick as they are RC4 ciphers.
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA